# Bootstrap button dropdown caret does not look right in Android 4.3 browser

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-frontend

Bootstrap dropdown caret is not drawing well.  It looks more like a rectangle than a triangle pointing down.

Anybody knows how to get around this issue?  I tried using one of the glyphs that come with bootstrap but it did not look good since the size is much bigger.

Thanks

This is what it looks like when you visit the official bootstrap website:

[image]

Comment: it seems you are on the official bootstrap site, am I right ?

Comment: Please check your console to see if there is any errors appear and try to open the page on different browser if that possible

Comment: @user4617883 Try to use some font icons for drop-down arrow.